# Entity Framework Core , client side computed columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to find a way to have a client side computed column in an easy fashion.
There already is the possibility to have computed columns on the server via :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/computed-columns

what I would like instead is something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
 .Property(p => p.DeptName)
 .HasClientComputedColumn( (context, entity) =>{        
            return myStaticMap[entity.Id];      
        });
```

Is it possible to do it with EF core?

Comment: If it's client side, why don't you just use custom C# property getter?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki  Well , I simplified a bit the problem and the solution seams to be as you said (even though that static map is horrible). What I wanted in fact is to define a a hardcoded `DBSet<Departments>` that can be queried by EF  eventhough it's values do not exist in the database. Can this be done ?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki you can answer the question and I will accept your answer  (maybe can you remove the need for the `static` dependency ?). I was looking for a GraphQL style of resolving data from different data sources

Comment: could you elaborate more on "maybe can you remove the need for the static dependency"?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki I am no expert in EF bug removing the static dependency would mean that the entity has some application data separate from the entity framework that is accessible from within the entity ... so static reference inside a getter is a way to go if we want to keep it simple. But then you wil have to make sure that the referenced static map is initialized before accessing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only a client-side column, then you don't need to use anything from Entity Framework. I would suggest implementing custom property getter in you `Person` class, like this:

```
class Person
{
    //other fields...

    public string DeptName
    {
        get
        {
            if(myStaticMap==null || !myStaticMap.Contains(this.Id))
            {
                //initialize your static map or throw exception
            }
            else
            {
                return myStaticMap[this.Id];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've assumed that `DeptName` property type is `string`, but obviously you should change it to match your needs.